# Applying Zorn's Lemma to natural numbers

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Zorn's Lemma states that if every chain $C$ in a partially ordered set $X$ has an upper bound then there is at least one maximal element in $X$.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $C_n \subset \mathbb{N}$ be the set containing the natural numbers $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then if $k\le n$, $C_k\subset C_n$, so $C_n$ is a chain. Also, $C_n$ has an upper bound, such as $n+1$. But what is the maximal element of $\mathbb{N}$?

There's something I don't get in Zorn's Lemma statement.

Comment: Well, your $C_n$ does not include every chain!

Comment: @I.Padilla Why does it need to include every chain?

Comment: @sequence Because Zorn's Lemma only applies if **every** chain has an upper bound. All you've shown is that the specific chains $C_n$ have upper bounds; so what?

Comment: Um... because that's a condition for Zorn's Lemma--- that *every* chain has an upper bound.  If C has no upper bound then it *can't* have a maximum element.  Zorn's Lemma does not apply to $\mathbb N$ because not every chain has an upper bound.

Comment: $C_n$ satisfies Zorn's Lemma and $C_n$ does have a maximal element.  But $C_n$ is not the same thing as $\mathbb N$.  For Zorn's lemma to apply to $\mathbb N$ then every chain in $\mathbb N$ must be bounded above.  That is not true for $\mathbb N$.  $C_e=\{2n|n \in \mathbb N\} = \{$even numbers\}$ is a chain that is not bounded above.  So Zorn's lemma does not apply to N.  You listed a bunch of chains that *were* bounded above--- but they were not ***all*** of the chains in $\mathbb N$.  So they don't matter.

Comment: So I think I hadn't completely understood the concept of chain from the definitions I'd read. I get now that a chain is any totally ordered set which is a subset of a partially ordered set. Moreover, a totally ordered set is also a partially ordered set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just take some examples of chains, but there are many others, for example the multiples of any positive integer is a chain. The hypothesis of the lemma is that every chain must have a upper bound, but $\mathbb{N}$ is a total ordered set, then every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a chain, in special, $\mathbb{N}$ itself is a chain.

The Zorn's lemma is quite useless in a total ordered set, because, if this set satisfies the hypothesis, the upperbound of the set itself (which is a chain) is the maximal element.